# Regex to match integers or word "other", case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

This seems simple enough but it's not working. I'm trying to match either an integer or the word "Other" (case insensitive). For example, given the array:

```
[1, 233, 45, "other", "the"]
```

Only the first 4 items in the array should be valid. However, currently my attempt will only match integers and is not capturing "other" (regardless of case insensitive).

This is the pattern and modifier that I'm using:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*|(other)$", "i"),
    match = regex.exec(value);

return match && (match.index === 0) && match[0].length === value.length;
```

Comment: Do you want a capturing group ?

Comment: don't need to capture it, just validate that the string is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is good but a few details need fixing :

```
var regex = /^(\d+|other)$/i;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it's capturing integers, it's capturing [0-9]*. The * means ZERO or more, so the empty string is valid. A + in it's place means one or more.

This is probably more general than you need, but numbers usually don't begin with a 0 except 0 itself, but if you don't mind allowing leading 0's, [0-9]+ will do. If you don't want to match numbers like 001, then you'll need something like 0|[1-9][0-9]*.

Also, the ^ and $ have greater precedence than |, which means you're actually matching anything starting with an empty string, or anything ending in 'other'

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:[0-9]+|other)$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/4

Comment: Still matches the empty string.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it wont now